# Extended Cox-model with ancillary variable

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I have survival data (coming from a labor market) looking like this

```
   gender  nation          profession year age event   survtime
1       F Austria  blue-/white-collar 1997  30  TRUE   707 days
2       M Austria          freelancer 2001  26  TRUE  1765 days
3       F Austria marginal employment 2006  57  TRUE    57 days
4       F Austria  blue-/white-collar 2011  33  TRUE   465 days
5       F Austria  blue-/white-collar 1997  22  TRUE    35 days
6       M Germany  blue-/white-collar 1996  38  TRUE   301 days
7       M Austria  blue-/white-collar 2007  24 FALSE  2251 days
8       F Germany  blue-/white-collar 2011  23  TRUE   172 days
9       M Austria  blue-/white-collar 2004  35  TRUE   249 days
10      M Austria          freelancer 2000  32  TRUE   366 days
11      M Germany  blue-/white-collar 2008  22  TRUE    64 days
12      F Austria  blue-/white-collar 1998  21  TRUE    56 days
13      M Austria  blue-/white-collar 2012  36 FALSE   200 days
14      F Austria  blue-/white-collar 2000  47  TRUE   841 days
15      F Austria  blue-/white-collar 2008  27  TRUE   117 days
16      F   other  blue-/white-collar 1971  24  TRUE 11324 days
17      M Austria          freelancer 2001  34  TRUE   456 days
18      M Austria  blue-/white-collar 2007  25  TRUE    31 days
19      F Austria  blue-/white-collar 1992  25  TRUE  2010 days
20      M   other  blue-/white-collar 2003  24  TRUE   347 days
```

(get it with `df <- source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WjQUatKy")$value`)

I would expect the `year`, which describes the year at which a labor contract started, to be an ancillary variable, meaning that I think that `survtime` is changing with the economic conditions (like when there is a recession, survtime is maybe shorter).

How can I account for that in an extended Cox proportional hazard model? I use R and so far I have

```
df <- source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WjQUatKy")$value
s <- Surv(as.numeric(df$survtime), df$event)
cox <- coxph(s ~ gender + nation + strata(profession) + age + year, data=df)
```

which however doesn't take this into account.